Why can't my Android phone play a sound on a nearby Apple AirTag?
I use a Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra with Android 13. There is an Apple AirTag near my phone, which was would be Android's tracker scanner. However, Android can't play a sound ln the AirTag.
Why can't my Android phone play a sound on a nearby Apple AirTag? The AirTag ID has not changed and it is not out of range. I haven't changed anything since the tracker scanner ran a few seconds ago.


Is it your AirTag or from someone else you don't know? There are ways to silent an AirTag on hardware level, may be this is why you don't hear a asound?

@Robert Thanks, it's my unaltered AirTag. It happily makes sounds when called from my iPhone.

Did you find a solution @FranckDernoncourt?

@Basj no~~~~~~~~
